# Spring cloud contract maven plugin is not installing jars to local .m2 folder

Tags: testing, spring-cloud, wiremock, spring-cloud-contract

I have spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin in my pom.xml of producer project. When I use the below plugin, it is not installing the jars to .m2 repository.

I have tried adding multiple versions of spring-cloud-contract and 2.0.2.RELEASE only seems stable to build successfully.

```
` <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <!--<executions>-->
          <!--<execution>-->
            <!--<goals>-->
              <!--<goal>convert</goal>-->
              <!--<goal>generateStubs</goal>-->
              <!--<goal>generateTests</goal>-->
            <!--</goals>-->
          <!--</execution>-->
        <!--</executions>-->
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
     <packageWithBaseClasses>com.sam.fraud.fcm.fraudcase.gateway.test.contracts</packageWithBaseClasses>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>`
```

If the above plugin is added in pom, .m2 folder is not at all getting installed dependency jars locall, stubs are generated but in target folder, .m2 not updated

```
`[INFO] Installing com.sam.fraud.fcm:fraud-case-gateway-api:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT at end`
```

If I remove the plugin or comment it out, I get the below, which is installing & working fine, but the stubs are not generated in the target, which I need.

```
`[INFO] Installing C:\Users\sam\FCM-forks\fraud-case-gateway-contract-tests\api\pom.xml to C:\Users\sam\.m2\repositoryFCM2\com\sam\fraud\fcm\fraud-case-gateway-api\1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\fraud-case-gateway-api-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom`
```

I need the correct plugin of this as, this is used with base class of tests and package. I have also tried with

```
 `<baseClassForTests>
          com.sam.fraud.fcm.fraudcase.gateway.test.contracts.RepreclientBase
        </baseClassForTests>`
```

Comment: Here you have an example of the setup that works fine https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tree/master/producer please follow it and things should work fine then

Comment: Thanks, Can you also tell me which version of spring -cloud to use with Spring Boot ?

Comment: In our project we have Spring Boot verison `2.1.2.RELEASE` & Spring cloud as `2.0.2.RELEASE`

Comment: We are getting this exception infinitely `3-05-2019 16:05:13.734 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].log - Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getHttpServletMapping()Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletMapping;
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setRequest(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:690)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.<init>(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:114)
 at

Comment: Please read the page https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud where you have the matrix of compatibility.

Comment: You can also use https://start.spring.io/ to generate a correct pom with compatible versions.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Marcin, but looks like I figured the issue, it was mvn-install plugin version which was not uploading jars locally, i reverted version to 2.4 from 2.5.4 so, it worked fine.

Alsom the infinite exception was related to wiremock-servlet issue with Spring Boot 2.
Using `javax-servlet-api:4.0.1` version helped me build & run my application successfully.